# Why the .net dlls generated for the same code and same .net framework version are not binary identical?

Tags: c#, .net, dll, compilation

I have a C# project which when compiled on different machines generate dlls which are not binary equal. So my question is why the generated dlls are different? and is there some way to get exactly same dll generated on different machines?

**EDIT**
Here is what i am trying to do. There are multiple client machines which get some code snippet from a server and compile it. After the dll is compiled, it get used over and over again on the client. If I could have the same DLLs generated on all machines then I can easily check that the DLL is not tampered with on the client side using cryptographic hash.

For some reasons the code has to be compiled at the client machine. Therefore digital signing is not an option.

Comment: Why would you need binary identical libraries? And also it would be nice to know the exact configuration of both involved machines, OS, .NET version, used IDEs or compilers.

Comment: Are you compiling with optimizations enabled? And why do you need to get files that are binary-equivalent? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Perhaps both projects have different assembly information set up? Like e.g. the GUID.

Comment: Clearly the configuration of the machines or compile settings are different in some way.  How different are they?  .net assemblies can contain build version information - is this the only difference?

Comment: @Bobby: The configurations are same.

Comment: @James Gaunt: Everything appears to be same. I suspect some information being added in DLL at compile time, may be some GUID or Timestamp!

Comment: @Barbar T.: Can you see how far into the files the bytes are different? Does it look like some header info, or there are differences all through the file?

Comment: @Steven Jeuris: The differences are at the very start and very end of files. Also, there is only small number of bytes that are different.

Comment: "I can easily check that the DLL is not tampered with on the client side using cryptographic hash." I don't understand how you want to do that. If the client is evil it can simply lie about the hash too.

Comment: @CodeInChaos: The client is also running my code. The client code and server communicate securely. I am not worried about the client to server communication security. I just need to ensure (some how) that the client will execute the same code (think of it  as a plugin) that it got from the server. Not sure if that is even possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<s>You cannot expect binaries to be same for any file recreated - let alone assemblies. All document metadata including data created, date modified will be different.</s>

If you need to compare, you need to sign the assembly (strong naming) and compare the public key token plus assembly version.

---

## UPDATE

What you are doing is asking for trouble although I can understand sometimes this has to be done. If I were you, I would compile the binary on server and get the clients to download the binary and not the code. At the end of the day, clients might not have the C# compiler on their machine.

To answer your question, **if you insist on compiling on client,** everytime you compile, create a local hash and store in registry, some file, etc and then compare that hash.

---

## UPDATE 2

C# compiler never guarantees that it is going to create the same binary. Many things are created at the compiled time for example naming anonymous functions, backing value for automatic properties, anonymous methods, internal GUIDs... all of these will be created at compile time and while compiler uses a naming convention which names end up usually the same, **it is not guaranteed**.

Comment: Yup, code signing is the appropriate solution here. The configurations of the machines are irrelevant. You have to use the right tool to solve the problem at hand.

Comment: I have updated the question and added details about the scenario. For some reasons the code has to be compiled at the client machine. Therefore digital signing is not an option.

Comment: I checked it to be sure, but at least for NTFS, the timestamp metadata is stored in the [Master File Table](http://www.ntfs.com/ntfs-files-types.htm) and not in the file. Ofcourse the compiler can still store an additional date, but this would seem useless to me.

Comment: Yes, silly of me - what I meant was document proerpties such as those in media files or office documents. I will update my answer...

Comment: +1: I was just comparing some binaries and noticed the behavior mentioned in Update 2. Furthermore, when building a Debug build, I experience some further variableness.

Comment: More specifically, varying `WrapNonExceptionThrows` occur in the compiled code when pdb is enabled. This is also enabled by default for Release builds. I noticed anonymous types due to using LINQ.

Comment: Yes. I would suggest you use the solution in UPDATE 1. That is what I would have used.

Comment: @Aliostad: I wish I could go with the downloading dll from server solution. Anyways, good answer, specially the point about anonymous functions. Thanks.

Comment: @Aliostad Not guaranteed is very different from not possible. C# compiler makes this task impossible as it irrevocably bakes in the build date.